# Calling parent method in class?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a class `Ant` that looks like this:

```js
function Ant(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.val = 2;
    this.direction = dirs[Math.floor(Math.random() * dirs.length)];
    this.carryingFood = false;

    this.inView = function () {
        fill("#008800");
        switch (this.direction.toString()) {
            case "0,1":
                return [
                    atXY(this.x - 1, this.y + 1),
                    atXY(this.x, this.y + 1),
                    atXY(this.x + 1, this.y + 1),
                ];
            case "1,1":
                return [
                    atXY(this.x, this.y + 1),
                    atXY(this.x + 1, this.y + 1),
                    atXY(this.x + 1, this.y),
                ];
            case "1,0":
                return [
                    atXY(this.x + 1, this.y + 1),
                    atXY(this.x + 1, this.y),
                    atXY(this.x + 1, this.y - 1),
                ];
            case "1,-1":
                return [
                    atXY(this.x + 1, this.y),
                    atXY(this.x + 1, this.y - 1),
                    atXY(this.x, this.y - 1),
                ];
            case "0,-1":
                return [
                    atXY(this.x + 1, this.y - 1),
                    atXY(this.x, this.y - 1),
                    atXY(this.x - 1, this.y - 1),
                ];
            case "-1,-1":
                return [
                    atXY(this.x, this.y - 1),
                    atXY(this.x - 1, this.y - 1),
                    atXY(this.x - 1, this.y),
                ];
            case "-1,0":
                return [
                    atXY(this.x - 1, this.y - 1),
                    atXY(this.x - 1, this.y),
                    atXY(this.x - 1, this.y + 1),
                ];
            case "-1,1":
                return [
                    atXY(this.x - 1, this.y),
                    atXY(this.x - 1, this.y + 1),
                    atXY(this.x, this.y + 1),
                ];
        }
    };

    this.move = function() {
        
        var possibleMoves = this.inView();
        if (!this.carryingFood) {
            for (let move of possibleMoves) {
                if (move.val == 3) {
                    this.x = move.x;
                    this.y = move.y;
                    this.carryingFood = true;
                    move.eat();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.draw = function () {
        fill("#FF0000");
        rect(this.x * cellSize, this.y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    };
}
```

the problem is in the line

```js
var possibleMoves = this.inView();
```

This currently will not work as `this` is pointing to `move`, not `Ant`. How could I access that function in `Ant`? Maybe take a different approach?

Comment: `this` shouldn't point to `move` unless you call `move` in a very strange way to start with. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin the error I get is `Property 'inView' does not exist on type 'move'.ts(2339)`

Comment: While the error message is useful, it isn't a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `function` with `() =>` (arrow function), then `this` will reference to parent.

```js
this.move = () => {
  var possibleMoves = this.inView();
  if (!this.carryingFood) {
      for (let move of possibleMoves) {
          if (move.val == 3) {
              this.x = move.x;
              this.y = move.y;
              this.carryingFood = true;
              move.eat();
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse arrow functions with lambda functions.

Comment: Interesting. So do arrow functions get parsed in a different way, which is why this works?

Comment: @Dion Sorry, as Quentin said it's `arrow function`, not `lambda`